# Restrict entries to specific users

Tags: craft3, users

I would like to restrict entries to specific users on the frontend via a User Field called userSelector. It should be possible to have more than 1 user. I understand groups might work, but I feel like it's easier to just select the user(s) directly on the entry.

I know the code below won't work, but hopefully, it shows my intentions a bit more.

```
{% set users = entry.userSelector.all() %}
{% if currentUser.email == users.email %}
    Show the page
{% else %}
    Permission Denied
{% endif %}
```

Very open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are faced with such a task, then I think it's better to use user IDs, getting from the method a `ids` from the field in which users are stored, and check the received array using the `in` method. Another option is a plugin https://plugins.craftcms.com/user-group-field.

```
 {% set usersIds = entry.usersField.ids %} 

    {% if currentUser.id in usersIds %} 
        Show the page
    {% else %}
        Permission Denied
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it.